# How to efficiently remove duplicates from list of lists (nested) containing dictionaries and integers?

Tags: python, list, dictionary, for-loop, list-comprehension

I have a list of lists, where each list contains a dictionary and integer. Sometimes duplicate lists occur, and I wish to remove these from the parent list directly. Currently, I am creating a new list and iterating over the old list to ensure only unique values are appended, but I feel this is bad practice. Can this be rewritten to a one-liner with list comprehension, or can the original list be filtered directly instead, for performance enhancement?

```
TRIAL=[[{'http': '46.101.160.223:80', 'https': '46.101.160.223:80'}, 0],
 [{'http': '66.70.178.214:9300', 'https': '66.70.178.214:9300'}, 0],
 [{'http': '130.61.100.135:80', 'https': '130.61.100.135:80'}, 0],
 [{'http': '157.245.27.9:3128', 'https': '157.245.27.9:3128'}, 0],
 [{'http': '185.246.84.7:8080', 'https': '185.246.84.7:8080'}, 0],
 [{'http': '185.246.84.7:8080', 'https': '185.246.84.7:8080'}, 0],
 [{'http': '130.61.100.135:80', 'https': '130.61.100.135:80'}, 1]]

#We have some duplicates which we want to filter out if there with function
temporary_list=[]
for i in TRIAL:
    if i[0] not in [item[0] for item in temporary_list]:
        temporary_list.append(i)

temporary_list (desired outcome)
[[{'http': '46.101.160.223:80', 'https': '46.101.160.223:80'}, 0],
 [{'http': '66.70.178.214:9300', 'https': '66.70.178.214:9300'}, 0],
 [{'http': '130.61.100.135:80', 'https': '130.61.100.135:80'}, 0],
 [{'http': '157.245.27.9:3128', 'https': '157.245.27.9:3128'}, 0],
 [{'http': '185.246.84.7:8080', 'https': '185.246.84.7:8080'}, 0]]
```

Comment: So the integers are irrelevant for comparison of uniqueness?  If so, does it matter which integer is saved in the new list?

Comment: Fair, I wasn't paying attention to this at all! It would be best to save the list with the highest integer in this case, but either way would work :)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

If you can use `pandas`:

```
import pandas as pd
df = pd.DataFrame(TRIAL, columns=['d', 'i'])
out = df.groupby(df['d'].apply(dict.values).apply(tuple)).last().values.tolist()
print(out)

[[{'http': '130.61.100.135:80', 'https': '130.61.100.135:80'}, 1],
 [{'http': '157.245.27.9:3128', 'https': '157.245.27.9:3128'}, 0],
 [{'http': '185.246.84.7:8080', 'https': '185.246.84.7:8080'}, 0],
 [{'http': '46.101.160.223:80', 'https': '46.101.160.223:80'}, 0],
 [{'http': '66.70.178.214:9300', 'https': '66.70.178.214:9300'}, 0]]
```

Answer (score 4):

You can try to use [`itertools.groupby`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/itertools.html#itertools.groupby) to group the similar elements and then pick the first one from the group (The `TRIAL` list needs to be sorted first):

```py
from itertools import groupby

TRIAL = [
    [{"http": "46.101.160.223:80", "https": "46.101.160.223:80"}, 0],
    [{"http": "66.70.178.214:9300", "https": "66.70.178.214:9300"}, 0],
    [{"http": "130.61.100.135:80", "https": "130.61.100.135:80"}, 0],
    [{"http": "157.245.27.9:3128", "https": "157.245.27.9:3128"}, 0],
    [{"http": "185.246.84.7:8080", "https": "185.246.84.7:8080"}, 0],
    [{"http": "185.246.84.7:8080", "https": "185.246.84.7:8080"}, 0],
    [{"http": "130.61.100.135:80", "https": "130.61.100.135:80"}, 1],
]

def key_func1(i):
    return i[0]['http'], i[0]['https'], -i[1]   # -i[1] because we want to pick the item with highest integer value fist

def key_func2(i):
    return i[0]['http'], i[0]['https']

out = []
for _, g in groupby(sorted(TRIAL, key=key_func1), key_func2):
    out.append(next(g))

print(out)
```

Prints:

```py
[
    [{"http": "130.61.100.135:80", "https": "130.61.100.135:80"}, 1],
    [{"http": "157.245.27.9:3128", "https": "157.245.27.9:3128"}, 0],
    [{"http": "185.246.84.7:8080", "https": "185.246.84.7:8080"}, 0],
    [{"http": "46.101.160.223:80", "https": "46.101.160.223:80"}, 0],
    [{"http": "66.70.178.214:9300", "https": "66.70.178.214:9300"}, 0],
]
```

Answer (score 2):

You could use [`polars`](https://www.pola.rs/).

```python
import polars as pl

df = pl.DataFrame(TRIAL, schema=["d", "i"])
out = [[d, i] for d, i in df.groupby("d").max().rows()]

print(out)
```

```
[[{'http': '157.245.27.9:3128', 'https': '157.245.27.9:3128'}, 0],
 [{'http': '185.246.84.7:8080', 'https': '185.246.84.7:8080'}, 0],
 [{'http': '46.101.160.223:80', 'https': '46.101.160.223:80'}, 0],
 [{'http': '130.61.100.135:80', 'https': '130.61.100.135:80'}, 1],
 [{'http': '66.70.178.214:9300', 'https': '66.70.178.214:9300'}, 0]]
```